# How to update a datetime field with PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How doesn't this work? Please help!!!

```
$query = "UPDATE User SET updated_date = NOW() WHERE pk_item = '$id'";
mysqli_query($this->link,$query);
if(mysqli_errno($this->link))
    return -1;
return 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [how to prevent it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Your query is vulnerable!

Comment: What is the output of mysql_error()? And what datatype is your "updated_date" field in the database?

Answer (score 1):

check length and  type of updated_date  is matching with  now()

or go with sysdate

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Answer (score 0):

If `$id` is a numeric field, you should not surround it with quotes. Just say:

```
pk_item = $id
```

If that's not it, then what error message are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any error message. It simply doesn't update. If I print the $query it says "UPDATE User SET updated_date = NOW() WHERE pk_item = '1'" which works fine if I type it on the mysql client shell. The PHP doesn't seems to work...

Comment: Have you tried any other queries with the same code? If no queries work the problem is somewhere in the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use [ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)?

Comment: I just want to update my field sometimes (when one of the other fields gets also updated).

Answer (score 0):

you can use date function from php like date("Y-m-d H:i:s") or something like this. don't forget to put it in single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a query

```
$query = 'UPDATE User 
          SET updated_date = NOW(),
          DOB = STR_TO_DATE("'.$DOB.'","%d-%m-%Y"), 
          WHERE pk_item ='.$id;
```

The above show two update column of datetime field
1.updated_date -> save current datetime
2.DOB -> save date of birth date and time

***Note: Always write a query in single quote the double quoted string is parse the string.***

For date time please ref the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880244/php-usering-str-to-date-update-datetime-column-but-its-updated-empty-record-l/24880375#24880375)