# PHP - usering STR_TO_DATE update datetime column but it's updated empty record like "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

```
$reg_date="10-09-1985 00:00:00"

$query = "UPDATE User 
          SET reg_date_time =  STR_TO_DATE("'.$reg_date.'","%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s"), 
          WHERE pk_item = '$id'";
```

The record is updated with empty reg_date_time="0000-00-00 00:00:00"

if

```
$reg_date ="10-09-1985 01:00:00"
```

then record updated correctly only when the reg_date contains hour value.

Comment: I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)` with your code :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the format `%h:%i:%s`

Here what happens in mysql

```
mysql> select str_to_date('10-09-1985 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s');
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('10-09-1985 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

So its returning NULL and on insert its not going, so you need to use the format `%H:%i:%s`

```
mysql> select str_to_date('10-09-1985 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('10-09-1985 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1985-09-10 00:00:00                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

For `10-09-1985 01:00:00` the date format is valid with `%h:%i:%s` so its working.

Its better to choose the date format `Y-m-d H:i:s` even with the input dates, since `10-09-1985 01:00:00` does not tell if its AM or PM and later doing date calculations become very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You set bad date format and bad quotes:

```
$query = "UPDATE User 
          SET reg_date_time =  STR_TO_DATE('".$reg_date."','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'), 
          WHERE pk_item = '$id'";
```

Comment: I've used your date format it's not working for me it give me "0000-00-00 00:00:00" value in updated column